# Why doesn't zip command include all files?

Tags: macos, command-line, zip

I am trying to zip an individual folder with no compression so I can easily copy the archive to a USB stick without having many thousands of files.

The problem is, the zip command is not doing what I think I'm telling it to do, because I'm apparently not telling it to do the right thing.

**What I want** is `asian.zip` to contain the complete folder structure and all the files within. Normally I would simply right-click in Finder and choose Compress, but I'd like to learn how to zip a folder without compressing.

Using the below directory structure (generated using https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree), I've tried:

---

```
zip -Z store asian.zip Asian
```

This results in `asian.zip`, which is 162 bytes, and contains an empty  folder `Asian`.

---

```
zip -Z store asian.zip Asian/*.*
```

This results in `asian.zip`, which is 258 bytes, and contains an empty folder `Asian/Capsule - 2005 - L.D.K. Lounge Designers Killer`. This is the only folder it put in there.

---

```
cd Asian/Aural\ Vampire\ -\ 2010\ -\ Zoltank
zip -Z store asian.zip *.*
```

This results in `asian.zip`, which is 146.9MB, and contains the folder `asian` that contains all the mp3 files that were inside the folder I was in.

---

```
├── Asian
│   ├── Aural\ Vampire\ -\ 2010\ -\ Zoltank
│   │   ├── 01\ -\ Flare\ Stack.mp3
│   │   ...(each folder listed is full of mp3 like this one)
│   ├── Aural\ Vampire\ -\ 2011\ -\ Kerguelen\ Vortex
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2004\ -\ SF\ -\ Sound\ Furniture
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2005\ -\ L.D.K.\ Lounge\ Designers\ Killer
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2005\ -\ Nexus-2060
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2006\ -\ Fruits\ Clipper
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2007\ -\ Flash\ Back
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2007\ -\ Sugarless\ GiRL
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2008\ -\ MORE!\ MORE!\ MORE!
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2009\ -\ Flash\ Best
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2010\ -\ PLAYER
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ 2012\ -\ Stereo\ Worxxx
│   ├── Capsule\ -\ Misc
│   ├── Faye\ Wong\ -\ Misc
│   ├── Globe\ -\ 1999\ -\ Cruise\ Records\ 1995-2000
│   ├── Globe\ -\ Misc
│   ├── Maximum\ The\ Hormone\ -\ 2004\ -\ Kusoban
│   ├── Maximum\ The\ Hormone\ -\ 2005\ -\ Rokkinpo\ Goroshi
│   ├── Maximum\ The\ Hormone\ -\ 2007\ -\ BuiikiKaesu
│   ├── Maximum\ The\ Hormone\ -\ Misc
│   ├── Maximum\ the\ Hormone\ -\ 2013\ -\ Yoshu�\204\ Fukushu�\204
│   ├── Misc
│   ├── OST\ -\ Chobits\ Original\ Soundtrack\ 001\ -\ 2003
│   ├── OST\ -\ Elfen\ Lied\ -\ 2004
│   ├── OST\ -\ Higurashi\ no\ Naku\ Koro\ ni\ Kai\ Vol\ 1\ -\ 2007
│   ├── OST\ -\ Higurashi\ no\ Naku\ Koro\ ni\ Vol\ 2\ -\ 2006
│   ├── OST\ -\ Noein\ -\ 2006
│   ├── She\ -\ 2006\ -\ Pioneer
│   └── She\ -\ 2008\ -\ Coloris
├── Industrial
├── Misc
├── Rock
├── Rockin
```

Comment: Try the `-r` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `--recurse-paths` option, or `-r` for short. Use this instead:

```
zip -rZ store asian.zip Asian
```

(I'm not on a Mac, but that should apply on both Mac and Linux.)